# Using Oauth2.0 / OpenId Hybrid to authenticate Android app and a Web Application (Backend Server)

Tags: java, android, oauth, openid

First please be kind, as I am still trying to grasp the whole OpenId/Oauth2.0.

I recently attended the Devoxx 2012 conference in Belgium.  Tim Bray [presented](https://oauth2-pres.appspot.com/#68) the ability to use a hybrid approach of Oauth2.0 and OpenId (I believe it is referred to as OpenId Connect).  Here is the [slide](https://oauth2-pres.appspot.com/#68) that describes it.  If I understood correctly, he stated that an Android app could authenticate (receive a token) then request a token for a server-side web application.  This would then allow the server side to receive the server token and check to see if the token is truly valid.  Validating that this is truly the authenticated user coming from the Android app.  Once this is done, then the server side web app can safely interact with the Android app.

I have been able to authenticate using the com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken for the Android app.

I have created a "Client ID for installed applications" under the API Access in the Google APIs Console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  I also created a web app under the same console, but when I follow the slides I am unable to get the token that should be sent to the web app (via https).  I am sure I am just missing a simple step or just don't fully understand it, but I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slide, it's written that the scope must be "audience:server:XXX".
But on [his blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html), Tim Bray says that scope is "audience:server:**client_id**:XXX"
Try this one.

Also, my mistake was to create 2 client ids in the same console but not in the same project. Ensure you did that right.

Comment: Thanks Barles, his blog post is much more helpful than his original presentation.  He glossed over this pretty quickly during the presentation, and probably wasn't really prepared.  But at least he followed up on it.